# using "ws.cell(row = row, column = columnl).value = looprow" removes previous data saved in python

Tags: python, excel

I'm new to openpyxl.

When I use "ws.cell(row = row, column = columnl).value = looprow" it removes the previous data that is saved.

Here's my code.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

looprow = 1
for i in range(1 , 10):
    writetocell = 3
    ws.cell(row = looprow, column = writetocell).value = looprow
    wb.save("/home/richard/Desktop/sample.xlsx")
    looprow += 1
```

What I'm trying to do is update sample.xlsx not overwrite. It deletes data from column A and B then add data to column C, what I'm trying to do is retain data of column A and B then add data to column C.

Comment: Should it be `ws = wb.active()`

Comment: it gives me error sir "ws = wb.active() TypeError: 'Worksheet' object is not callable" 
what you mean is wb.get_active_sheet() but still the same it still overwrites sample.xlsx not update or should I say it deletes the previous data and creates a new one

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not using the same Excel. You are creating a new excel and replacing it in the old Excel position .

In the following program I have read teh same Excel made changes to that excel and have override that excel with new one

**Code:**

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
wb=load_workbook("/home/richard/Desktop/sample.xlsx")
ws=wb.get_active_sheet()
looprow = 1
for i in range(1 , 10):
    writetocell = 3
    ws.cell(row = looprow, column = writetocell).value = looprow
    looprow += 1

wb.save("/home/richard/Desktop/sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: @Newboy11 if you don't mind can you accept it by clicking the tick button